# How would a Jack gain esoteries?

Tags: numenera

I recently looked at **Wields Power with Precision**, a focus in Discovery. It says that it improves the use of esoteries, so mainly Nanos use it. But then it mentions

> some Jacks do as well.

How would a Jack gain esoteries? I thought they were for Nanos only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of the confusion lies in the fact the Jack changed significantly between the original book (2013) and "Numenera 2" (Destiny and Discovery), while a lot of text was reused.

In the original book, the Jack's tricks were often taken whole cloth from the other two lists. At second tier, for instance, their options were

- Brute Finesse (Jack exclusive)
- Experienced Adventurer (Jack exclusive)
- No Need for Weapons (Glaive)
- Push (Nano)
- Reload (Glaive)
- Ward (Nano)

This changed in Numenera 2 when the class identities were solidified and Arkus, Wright, and Delve were added. The Jack doesn't recycle abilities anymore, so the only remaining options are

- Consider all Jack "supernatural" abilities as esoteries. Clear cut for some, like Link Senses [Discovery 48] or Jaunt [Discovery 50].
- Memory Becomes Action [Discovery 50] explicitly allows the Jack to copy an esotery they've seen.
- Learn an esotery or esotery-like ability by spending XP on a medium term benefit [Discovery 126].

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 8):

As of Discovery, Jacks can gain Nano esoteries starting at Tier 2.

> Tricks of the Trade: (From tier 2 onward) Choose one of the following tricks (or a trick from a lower tier) to add to your repertoire. Instead of selecting a trick, you can select a lower-tier Glaive fighting move or Nano esotery.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 2):

We can read these about Jacks:

> Jacks are the most flexible of the character types, and advanced jacks
>   are no different. Some learn esoteries, as nanos do. (Core 41)
>
> Some of these tricks of the trade are technically esoteries, using the
>   numenera, while others are more mundane. (Core 42)
>
> Although technically “esoteries” are nano abilities, jacks often refer
>   to their more clearly supernatural tricks of the trade as esoteries as
>   well. (Core 42, sideline)

Thus some Tricks can be considered esoteries, and would be affected by other abilities as such. Which are esoteries is not indicated clearly, and it seems up to the GM to decide which ones count as one.